# Python mock returns a MagicMock object instead of a specified result value

Tags: python, testing, mocking

I want to mock test this function:

```
def foo():
  client = boto3.client(some_args)
  return client.func_A(other_args)
```

So I mock boto3 in my test:

```
def test_foo():
  with patch('boto3') as mock_boto3:
    mock_boto3.return_value.client.return_value.func_A.return_value = 'test_val'
    foo()
```

The proiblem with this is that `func_A` returns a `MagicMock` object instead of the specified return value. What am I doing wrong?

`<MagicMock name='boto3.client().func_A()' id='140131668642896'>`

Comment: You're not *calling* `boto3`, you've got a `return_value` there that doesn't match the code under test.

Comment: Oh, now I get it. The test code has to be like `mock_boto3.client.return_value.func_A.return_value = 'test_val'`. Thanks.